# Converting HTML unicode to java unicode characters

Tags: java, html, unicode

From server, I am receiving a response in HTML unicode characters like `&#x9053;` . In my device, I need to convert these characters to Java Unicode characters.

I browsed through online. I found some few solutions using `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4()` using apache common library. But I don't use this.

Is there any method in JAVA to convert these characters or if we wrote functions that just replaces `&#x` with `\u` will it be reliable and consistent ?

Can somebody please help ?

Comment: in IntelliJ you can change you format in the bottom-right side of your IDE. rightclick on windows-15XX and toggle Uni-8. Afterwards IntelliJ asks you if you want to refractor youre code :) I think other IDEs got the same function

Comment: Just replacing `&#x` with `\u` and removing the `;` will not be enough, because HTML uses other formats as well. `&#345;` with decimal numbers and `&rcaron;` with names. Also I seem to remember reading that Java doesn't do escaping for non-BMP codepoints, so you would have to replace `&#x1D563;` with two 16-bit values. Not to mention HTML's encoding in  different codepages!

Comment: What's wrong with the Apache Commons?

Comment: Why exactly do you need the characters in `\uXXXX` format? Java uses that format for *source code*, but if you want to have that text inside a `String` in your program, then you don't use those `\u` escapes, you just put the decoded characters in your String. Or are you writing that text to a file?